# Google Authentication using Tornado Web Framework(Python)

Tags: python, tornado

I am using the Tornado Web Framework for its's asynchronous call back facilities, and trying to setup a Google authentication using OAuth in Tornado.

Currently the authentication goes to the step where it ask for my permissions to access the data and then a `No Data Received` screen comes up as it is not able to exchange the access token with my application.

Comment: what is done thus far

Answer (score 0):

can you update your question with some code ?? i can update my answer based on the error or the code you update.

if you want to refer to some docs u can look at http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/auth.html

below is an example code which would help you.

```
class GoogleOAuth2LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler,
                               tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri='http://your.site.com/auth/google',
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            # Save the user with e.g. set_secure_cookie
        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri='http://your.site.com/auth/google',
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['profile', 'email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})
```